# How do I tag books in CloudReaders?

Tags: ipad, applications

I have the [CloudReaders](http://itunes.apple.com/au/app/cloudreaders-pdf-cbz-cbr/id363484920?mt=8) app on my iPad.  According to its release notes and other reviews of it, it supports tagging of books to allow for filtering.  However, for the life of me I can't figure out how to do it - only how to search based off tags?  Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After another 30 minutes of playing, it turned out (competely illogically) the reply/share button leads to a tagging UI.